# Add custom content after redirect wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've created a function redirecting all my logged-out users to the membership page.

I want them to buy a package plan before they can view the page they tried to visit before being redirected.

If logged-in -> view the download page.
If logged-out -> redirect to the membership page -> purchase a package -> view the download page.

I want to add content to the membership page, something like:
**'The product that you are trying to download cannot be purchased individually, but it's part of our membership package'**

The problem is that I couldn't find a way to execute any function after the `wp_redirect()` function. So I don't know how to display the content only to those redirected.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

in your header.php:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    nocache_headers();
    wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( 'YOUR_MEMBERSHIP_PAGE_ID' ) . '?message=true' );
    exit;
}
```

in your functions.php:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "message";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

in your membership page:

```
if( get_query_var('message') && !is_user_logged_in() ){
        echo 'The product that you are trying to download cannot be purchased individually, but it\'s part of our membership package';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to achieve it just with the functions.php file and some jQuery?

Comment: this is a more effective way than with jquery, using wordpress functions

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to achieve it just by using the functions.php file instead of the header and the membership page?

Comment: you would need to echo out the statement somehow, so you would need to put code in your membership page